# How rails ActiveRecord or Nosql ORM like mongoid handle has_many, has_one side of the relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Lets Say I have User and a Team model.

```
    class User
      #some fields
      has_one :team
    end

    class Team
       #some fields
       belongs_to :user
    end
```

Now when i do `User.last.update(team: Team.last)`, it stores user_id: foreign key in team  document. Prety common stuff.

I want to know what ORMs do/store on the has_one/has_many models(User) just like they store foreign_key on belongs_to(Team) model so that `User.last.team` query actually gives me a team. Does it create instance methods on `User` model like

```
  def team
    Team.where(user_id: self.id).first
  end
```

Am I wrong?

Comment: My answer below is a really long way of saying, you're basically right but with a small tweak.

Answer (score 2):

Okay I can definitely explain what's going on here. Given the following models:

```rb
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  #some fields
  has_one :team
end

class Team
  include Mongoid::Document
  #some fields
  belongs_to :user
end
```

We can create the documents as follows:

```rb
Team.create!(user: User.create!)
```

This is equivalent to what you did in the OP. Now, this yields the following documents:

```rb
> db.users.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("62d9ad683282a400a799c7e7") }
> db.teams.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("62d9ad683282a400a799c7e8"), "user_id" : ObjectId("62d9ad683282a400a799c7e7") }
```

As you can see, the foreign key is stored on the `belongs_to` side of the relationship. Now, when trying to retrieve the team from the user:

```rb
User.last 
# => #<User _id: 62d9adc63282a400c637b234, >
User.last.team
```

The `take` method (as of Mongoid 8, before that, the first method was used) is used on the following criteria:

```rb
#<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {"user_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('62d9adc63282a400c637b234')}
  options:  {}
  class:    Team
  embedded: false>
```

To put this into layman's terms, we are searching the Team collection for a document with the same value for user_id as our user's _id.

So yes, your idea is almost correct, it's more like:

```
Team.where(user_id: user._id).take
```

The difference between `take` and `first` is that `take` doesn't put a sort on `_id`, while `first` does. Using `take` is a little more efficient.